# FIFO Capital Gains Calculations in Python

Tags: pandas, numpy, finance, fifo

I'm trying to calculate capital gains on some earnings in python but having a bit of trouble figuring out the right data structures to use and the best approach for doing what I want to do because I need to account for long-term and short-term tax rate differences.

Below is a typical representation of the data:

[image: Transactions Example]

Unfortunately, I don't think I can simply add and subtract dollar-cost averages because buying at 50 @ $50 on Jan 1, 2017 50 @ $50 on Feb 1, 2017 and selling 100 @ $100 on Jan 15, 2018 results in long term cap gains (15%) for the first 50 units and short term cap gains (25%) on the second 50 units.

So it seems like with every sale, I still need to keep track of all prior sales @ particular sale dates, but I also have to amend the first X records to reflect that these purchases have been partially/fully depleted.

I don't know how to do this or what data structure works best for this?

Comment: Not sure if I've got it: You want to determine if sold item was kept longer or shorter than a year? Your table also doesn't reflect what you describe in the text.

Comment: A FIFO data structure is all you need for FIFO accounting, no? You can just have mutable `CostBasis` objects in a linked list, each encapsulating a `quantity`, `price`, and `date`. Subtract out each sale's quantity from the head `CostBasis` object's quantity, and once the head `CostBasis` object's quantity is 0, poll the list so that the next `CostBasis` (e.g. 2/1/2017) becomes the head. Calculate the difference between the sale price and the purchase `price` from the `CostBasis` object to get the capital gains and use the elapsed days to determine whether they are long-term or short-term.